# Backbone collection length always set to one with nested views

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

When the view is loaded, the collection length always return 1 while there is currently 3 members shows up in the parse function. I wondered if the problem was the nested item view, but it seems to behave the same without ! I don't understand why the self.push(member) does not add the model to the collection ! Bit stuck here, any help please ?

**The model**

```
define([
'backbone'
], function(Backbone) {
'use strict';

var MemberModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  id: "_id"

});

return MemberModel;

});
```

**The collection**

```
define([
'backbone', 
'models/MemberModel' 
], function(Backbone, MemberModel) {
'use strict';

var Members = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MemberModel,
  url: '/api/v1/users',

  parse: function(response, options) {
     var self = this;

     _.each(response.users, function(item){
        var member = new self.model();
        member.set('email', item.email);
        member.set('firstname', item.firstname);
        member.set('lastname', item.lastname);
        member.set('group', item.group);
        member.set('city', item.city);

        // shows every member's emails
        console.log('member.email='+member.get('email'));
        self.push(member);

     });

     console.log('this.length='+this.length); // this is always equal to 1
     return this.models;

  }

});

return Members;


});
```

**The view**

```
define([
'collections/members',                        
'views/membersItem',
'text!templates/members.html'
], function(MembersCollection, MembersItem, membersTpl) {
'use strict';

var Members = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#settings-content',
   template: _.template(membersTpl),

  events: {
     'click #edit-member': 'editMember'
  },

  initialize: function() {     
     this.collection = new MembersCollection(); 

     this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
     this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

     var self = this;

     this.collection.fetch({
        success: function() {
           self.renderMember();
        }
     });

     return this;
  },

  renderMember: function() {     
     // same here collection length = 1
     console.log('collection.length:'+this.collection.length);

     _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
        var memberView = new MembersItem({model: item});
        $('.list-item', this.el).append(memberView.render().el);
     }, this);

  }


});

return Members;
});
```

**The nested item view**

```
define([                    
'text!templates/members_item.html'
], function(membersItemTpl) {
'use strict';

var MembersItem = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "tr",
  className: '.item',
   template: _.template(membersItemTpl), 

  initialize: function() {
     this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
  },

  render: function() {
     this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
     return this;
  }

 });

 return MembersItem;
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with duplicated `id's` in the collection. It is supposed to be a **unique Identifier.**

Set the **idAttribute** inside the model and make sure, the id's for the 3 objects in question are different.

```
var MemberModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "_id"

});
```

If your id is duplicated then the model will not be added to the model.

If that does not work try setting the `id` Attribute explicitly

```
 _.each(response.users, function(item, index){
        var member = new self.model();
        member.set('_id', index);
```

Comment: Damn! Thanks a lot. You saved my day :)